# Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null ( in the EventEmitter ) How to solve this issue?

Tags: node.js, npm, typeerror, blockchain

in the file common.ts

import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

.............................................

export class Common extends EventEmitter {
public readonly DEFAULT_HARDFORK: string | Hardfork;

```
private _chainParams: ChainConfig;
private _hardfork: string | Hardfork;
private _eips: number[] = [];
private readonly _customChains: ChainConfig[];

private readonly HARDFORK_CHANGES:
```

....................................

How i can solve this issue

this issue in the file common.ts in the node_modules which is automatically created when we type the command "npm install"